How to create1080p and 4k black png background text in center using ffmpeg?
I’m trying to create a png black background with text in center using ffmpeg I left an image example from Canva. Please someone help by giving command line/parameters example for 1080p and 4K?

ffmpeg -lavfi "color=black:1920x1080, drawtext=text='Example' :fontsize=h/8 :fontcolor=white :x=(w-tw)/2 :y=(h-th)/2" -frames 1 out.png

Yup, and 4k is 3840×2160.

@БаярГончикжапов please add your answer as an Answer (and not simply as a comment) so it can be accepted and voted on

@EddieValentin this should be cross-platform

My question has been answered. Thank You

it works but id like to add a font arial? in this command please? ffmpeg -lavfi "color=black:1920x1080, drawtext=text='Example' :fontsize=h/8 :fontcolor=white :x=(w-tw)/2 :y=(h-th)/2" -frames 1 out.png

@EddieValentin you simply add :font=Arial in the drawtext part, like this: ffmpeg -lavfi "color=black:1920x1080, drawtext=text='Example' :font=Arial :fontsize=h/8 :fontcolor=white :x=(w-tw)/2 :y=(h-th)/2" -frames 1 out.png (@Баяр Гончикжапов
add it as an Answer)
